# opacity and z-index together?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, z-index, opacity

The following is an extract from a much larger code. My purpose is to **dim** the page and then produce some div on top of the dimmed page (i.e., modal dialog). However, the div on top, although having a larger z-index, is also dimmed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">

  <div id="dim" style="position:fixed;
    left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;
    background-color:black; opacity:0.5; z-index:100;">
  </div>

  <div id="main" style="position:relative;
    left:0; top:0; width:400px; height:200px;
    background-color:red; z-index:10;">

      <div id="top" style="position:absolute;
        left:40px; top:20px; width:320px; height:160px;
        background-color:yellow; z-index:110;">
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its because, the `opacity` of the parent is affecting all of its child elements.

Comment: But "dim" is not a parent of "top"...

Comment: actually the thing is , you've set `z-index: 100` for the very first element with having `opactiy: 0.5` and since its overlapping all other elements as the very next element has `z-index: 10`, its affecting them also.

Comment: Ok, I guess I understood the concept of "parent" differently... so how can I achieve the goal of having "dim" dimming everything except "top"?

Comment: Its simple just give `#dim` `z-index:5` viz less than `#main` and it will do the trick.

Comment: But in that case it does not dim "main"... My goal is to dim "main" but not "top"...

Comment: Use `background:rgba()` on `#dim` and set the last value to anything less than 1. That will create an opaque background color... e.g. `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)` http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/

Comment: Actually even in the above jsfiddle demo, if you change the opacity from 1 to, say, 0.5 -- it blurs also the modal dialog itself.

Comment: FWIW found this: [http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)